# show and hide div depending upon selected checkbox with combobox option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, combobox

I have used [**this**](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/) multiselect checkbox with a combobox option..

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2XTy4/)

In my jsfiddle that checkbox with a combobox type will not work. I have too many codes. So, I didn't included. See this [**link**](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/) for full codes I'm trying to show and hide the div content depending upon selected checkbox. it does not work. I tried this code separately (without a combobox checkbox only). it works. I have problem with checkbox with a combobox type. How do I show/hide div content based upon selected checkbox with combobox option?

[**Without Combobox Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2XTy4/1/)

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("option_1").onclick = function() {
    if(this.checked)
        document.getElementById('choose_the_correct_answer').style.display = "block";
    else
        document.getElementById('choose_the_correct_answer').style.display = "none";
    }
```

I have tried this **Jquery** code too

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#option_1').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        $("#choose_the_correct_answer").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#choose_the_correct_answer").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="control_3" name="control_3[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option id="option_1" value="option_1">Choose the Correct Answer</option>
    <option id="option_2" value="option_2">Fill in the Blanks</option>
    <option id="option_3" value="option_3">True or False</option>
    <option id="option_4" value="option_4">Match the Following</option>
    <option id="option_5" value="option_5">Two Mark Questions</option>
    <option id="option_6" value="option_6">Five Mark Questions</option>
    <option id="option_7" value="option_7">Others</option>
</select>
<div id="choose_the_correct_answer">choose the correct answer</div>
<div id="fill_in_the_blanks">fill in the blanks</div>
<div id="true_or_false">true or false</div>
<div id="match_the_following">match the following</div>
<div id="two_mark_questions">two mark questions</div>
<div id="five_mark_qustions">five mark questions</div>
<div id="others">others</div>
```

Comment: :you need multiselect right ??

Comment: @SajadLfc : I need multiselect option

Comment: did you check my answer and fiddle ??

Comment: your answer worked on fiddle. but, not in my coding. because, i used this http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/ checkbox with combobox options...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
 $('#option_1').on('click', function() {
});
```

and

the condition should be

```
if ( this.value == 'option_1')
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Aqa8/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#option_1').on('click', function() {      
      if ( this.value == 'option_1')
      {
        $("#choose_the_correct_answer").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#choose_the_correct_answer").hide();
      }

    });
});
```

**UPDATE**:

AND a better option will be to use [**.togggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) if you intend to use multiselect

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Aqa8/2/)

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('option').on('click', function() {         
      if ( this.value == 'option_1')
      {
        $("#choose_the_correct_answer").toggle();
      }
       else if ( this.value == 'option_2')
      {
        $("#fill_in_the_blanks").toggle();
      }
      else if ( this.value == 'option_3')
      {
        $("#true_or_false").toggle();
      }
       else if ( this.value == 'option_4')
      {
        $("#match_the_following").toggle();
      }
       else if ( this.value == 'option_5')
      {
        $("#two_mark_questions").toggle();
      }
      else if ( this.value == 'option_6')
      {
        $("#five_mark_qustions").toggle();
      }
      else if ( this.value == 'option_7')
      {
        $("#others").toggle();
      }  
    });
});
```

**New Update**: using normal dropdown with multiselect

use

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Aqa8/4/)

Comment: how do i select multiple option with this normal comobobox option http://jsfiddle.net/3Aqa8/3/

Comment: @Beginner: for that use  $('select').on('change', function() {